# PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, alamofire

I've already tried to do lock & unlock keys, to update pods, to clean build folder but nothing above does not help me. 
Please help!

```
mkdir -p /Users/ulanzeniserov/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Balaq-bnrzxotbjdjuukdlsfymccucvfgi/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Balaq.app/Frameworks
rsync --delete -av --filter P .*.?????? --filter "- CVS/" --filter "- .svn/" --filter "- .git/" --filter "- .hg/" --filter "- Headers" --filter "- PrivateHeaders" --filter "- Modules" "/Users/ulanzeniserov/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Balaq-bnrzxotbjdjuukdlsfymccucvfgi/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Alamofire/Alamofire.framework" "/Users/ulanzeniserov/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Balaq-bnrzxotbjdjuukdlsfymccucvfgi/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Balaq.app/Frameworks"
building file list ... done
Alamofire.framework/
Alamofire.framework/Alamofire
Alamofire.framework/Info.plist

sent 3452840 bytes  received 70 bytes  6905820.00 bytes/sec
total size is 3452177  speedup is 1.00
Stripped /Users/ulanzeniserov/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Balaq-bnrzxotbjdjuukdlsfymccucvfgi/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Balaq.app/Frameworks/Alamofire.framework/Alamofire of architectures: armv7
Code Signing /Users/ulanzeniserov/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Balaq-bnrzxotbjdjuukdlsfymccucvfgi/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Balaq.app/Frameworks/Alamofire.framework with Identity iPhone Developer: Aibek Rakhim (4FM85TMDZ7)
/usr/bin/codesign --force --sign 40E5552EA3812A40C344043B8F77C0DF2B504157  --preserve-metadata=identifier,entitlements '/Users/ulanzeniserov/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Balaq-bnrzxotbjdjuukdlsfymccucvfgi/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Balaq.app/Frameworks/Alamofire.framework'
/Users/ulanzeniserov/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Balaq-bnrzxotbjdjuukdlsfymccucvfgi/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Balaq.app/Frameworks/Alamofire.framework: errSecInternalComponent
Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code
```

Answer (score 2):

The `errSecInternalComponent` is related to code signing and keychain access. Follow these steps which worked for me:

- With your project open in Xcode, hold down Command + Option + Shift + K
- Select Clean when prompted and close Xcode.
- Open Keychain Access and find the iOS Developer certificate in a tab called Local/Login.
- Drag and drop the certificate from Local/Login to the System tab.
- Enter admin password when prompted.
- Delete any old certificates.
- Start Xcode and re-run your project.

Comment: Did not help me ... apparently, I have a signing issue with regard to Firebase?!?